# How to properly work with nested enums in Rust?

Tags: rust, enums

I am new to Rust, so it is entirely possible that I'm trying a completely wrong approach, so please suggest a better one if necessary :)

Say, I'm writing a CPU emulator, and I want to organize functions that implement assembly instructions in a nice and convenient way, by using enums to define instructions and their addressing mode variants.

My first thought was to implement instruction decoder as a function like `pub fn scan_instr(mem: &[u8], pc: &mut usize)` (where `mem` represents a memory block with binary code, and `pc` is an instruction pointer), and represent all opcodes as a nested enum, like so:

```
pub enum Opcode {
    ADC(ADC), // add with carry
    AND(AND), // and (with accumulator)
    ASL(ASL), // arithmetic shift left
    BCC(BCC), // branch on carry clear
    BCS(BCS), // branch on carry set
    // and so on...
}

// Instruction enum with addressing mode variants
pub enum ADC {
    IMM = 0x69,  // ADC #oper,    2 bytes
    ZP = 0x65,   // ADC oper,     2 bytes
    ZPX = 0x75,  // ADC oper,X,   2 bytes
    ABS = 0x6D,  // ADC oper,     3 bytes
    ABSX = 0x7D, // ADC oper,X,   3 bytes
    ABSY = 0x79, // ADC oper,Y,   3 bytes
    INDX = 0x61, // ADC (oper,X), 2 bytes
    INDY = 0x71  // ADC (oper),Y, 2 bytes
}

pub enum AND {
    IMM = 0x29,  // AND #oper,    2 bytes
    ZP = 0x25,   // AND oper,     2 bytes
    ZPX = 0x35,  // AND oper,X,   2 bytes
    ABS = 0x2D,  // AND oper,     3 bytes
    ABSX = 0x3D, // AND oper,X,   3 bytes
    ABSY = 0x39, // AND oper,Y,   3 bytes
    INDX = 0x21, // AND (oper,X), 2 bytes
    INDY = 0x31  // AND (oper),Y, 2 bytes
}

// and so on...
```

Then, I would fetch next instruction byte from the memory array, use it as an `Opcode` enum variant, and match it to determine which instruction it is, then pass it to the corresponding function and let it further determine the particular addressing mode by itself.
While this would be trivial with a "flat" enum, it's not quite clear to me how to do it with such nested enum in Rust (if even possible). I suspect this might be a wrong approach entirely, any suggestions?

Comment: Are you asking "How can I convert from a binary opcode to a nested enum?" An `impl From<u8> for Opcode` is a good place to start, where it may need to `try_from` for each variant until one clicks. You could also construct a look-up table that makes this easier, even programmatically if you're not shy about Rust macros.

Comment: I am not certain if I understand your question. So you have an `Opcode` and you want to match it, and then call the apropriate function. Say, `match opcode { Opcode::Adc(adc) => handle_adc(adc), /*...*/ }` and in `handle_adc` you would like to `match adc { Adc::IMM => /*...*/ }`. If that's the case, you could do it exactly like that.

Comment: @tadman could you please expand on that a little bit? I've been looking into implementing `TryFrom for Opcode` trait, while using `num_derive` for every sub-enum with `#[derive(FromPrimitive)]`, but I'm not sure where to go from there, that's where I got stuck

Answer (score 0):

Rust supports pattern matching so you could match the `Opcode` variant and pass the inner enum type to the function.

```rust
match opcode {
    Opcode::ADC(adc) => handle_adc(adc),
    Opcode::AND(and) => handle_and(and),
    _ => todo!(),
}
```

and the functions can match their enum

```rust
fn handle_adc(adc: ADC) {
    match adc {
        ADC::IMM => todo!(),
        ADC::ZP => todo!(),
        _ => todo!(),
    }
}

fn handle_and(and: AND) {
    match and {
        AND::IMM => todo!(),
        AND::ZP => todo!(),
        _ => todo!(),
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=454604fc0d8bac92157d2dfc31dfbfb5)

## Edit

If your opcode starts as `u8`, you can implement converter using `TryFrom` trait.

```rust
pub struct OpcodeError;

impl TryFrom<(u8, u8)> for Opcode {
    type Error = OpcodeError;
    fn try_from(v: (u8, u8)) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match v.0 {
            // I just used random numbers since I don't know the real ones
            0x00 => Ok(Opcode::ADC(ADC::try_from(v.1)?)),
            0x11 => Ok(Opcode::AND(AND::try_from(v.1)?)),
            _ => Err(OpcodeError),
        }
    }
}
impl TryFrom<u8> for ADC {
    type Error = OpcodeError;
    fn try_from(v: u8) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match v {
            0x69 => Ok(ADC::IMM),
            0x65 => Ok(ADC::ZP),
            _ => Err(OpcodeError),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let opcode = Opcode::try_from((0x00, 0x65)).unwrap();
    dbg!(&opcode);
}
```

You could use [strum](https://docs.rs/strum/latest/strum/index.html) crate, specifically `FromRepr` trait to automatically derive these conversions. Although for the nested enum (`Opcode`), you'll have to manually implement conversion since the macro just fills the inner value with its default value. Also you might want to look at `#[repr(u8)]` macro if you need to assign value to your opcode variants.

[Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bde6f771b7f74fac81a2ddcd0a4e142f)

Comment: This would work fine and dandy, given that I already have `opcode` represented as `Opcode` variant, and not `u8` - and this is exactly the part I'm stuck at...

Comment: @Feliksas Could you provide a simple test case for what you have and what you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

I would use cascading matches like this:

```
match opcode {
    Opcode::ADC(adc) => match adc {
        ADC::IMM  => adc_imm(),
        ADC::ZP   => adc_zp(),
        ADC::ZPX  => adc_zpx(),
        ADC::ABS  => adc_abs(),
        ADC::ABSX => adc_absx(),
        ADC::ABSY => adc_absy(),
        ADC::INDX => adc_indx(),
        ADC::INDY => adc_indy(),
    }
    Opcode::AND(and) => match and {
        AND::IMM  => and_imm(),
        AND::ZP   => and_zp(),
        AND::ZPX  => and_zpx(),
        AND::ABS  => and_abs(),
        AND::ABSX => and_absx(),
        AND::ABSY => and_absy(),
        AND::INDX => and_indx(),
        AND::INDY => and_indy(),
    }
    …
}
```

For the fastest assignment of the opcodes to their numerical values, an array `[Opcode;256]` would be suitable, where each `Opcode` is at the corresponding numeric index in the array.